# Java Split excluyendo rango

Tags: java, split

Recibo un `String` en java con un formato valor y rango `[x,y,z]` de manera que el String de entrada es `valor[x,y,z]` (ejemplo `20[4Y,2W,4H]`).

Puedo tener valores con una condicion `or` (representado con una ',') de manera que el `String` de entrada puede ser `20[4Y,2W,4H] , 10[2Y,1W,5H]`.

Estoy intentando como obtener estos dos string `20[4Y,2W,4H]` y `10[2Y,1W,5H]` pero al hacer el `split` tambien me tiene en cuenta los de dentro de `[ ]`.

Hay alguna manera de hacer el `split` excluyendo los de dentro del `[ ]` sin tener que encadenar `splits`?

El rango es opcional por lo que tendria tambien que encadenar `if` para comprobar si se ha introducido o no.

Comment: Has probado a hacerlo así? `split("] ,")` Si lo haces separando con el corchete de cierre y la coma, cuando haya más de 1 te los separará pero te suprimirá el corchete de cierre donde lo almacenes, si lo quieres se lo tendrás que concatenar

Comment: Hola Roger, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Mira lo que te sugiere Pablo. Y para mejorar la pregunta, mira [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Lo pude lograr utilizando la sobrecarga que acepta una expresion regular:

```
  String data = "20[4Y,2W,4H] , 10[2Y,1W,5H]";

   String[] parametros = data.split("(?<=])\\s*[,]\\s*");

   for(String a : parametros)
   {
       System.out.println(a);// imprime 20[4Y,2W,4H] y 10[2Y,1W,5H]
   }
```

La idea era buscar los caracteres que separan un valor del otro, en este caso, la  `,`. Pero como hay varias comas lo que hize fue que busque un corchete de cierre `]` seguido de una coma `,`.

Explicacion de la expresion:

`(?<=])` = Busca el texto que termine con `]` pero no lo incluya en el resultado.

`\\s*`   = Seguido de 0 o mas espacios

`[,]`    = Seguido de una coma

`\\s*`   = Seguido de 0 o mas espacios

Comment: los corchetes en `[ , ]`  sobran

Comment: Dices cambiarlo por `\\,`?

Comment: no, simplemente dejar la expresion como `"(?<=])\\s*,\\s*"`. Mira este [ejemplo online](https://www.ideone.com/H42EGg) (puedes incluirlo en la respuesta si quieres :P)

Answer (score 0):

> String de entrada es `valor[x,y,z]` (valor y rango)
>   El rango es **opcional**.
>
> hacer el `split` excluyendo los de dentro del `[ ]`
>   Ejemplo: `20[4Y,2W,4H] , 10[2Y,1W,5H]` --> `20[4Y,2W,4H]` y `10[2Y,1W,5H]`

Si el espacio solamente se presenta alrededor de la coma que separa valores, podrías usar `" , "` como delimitador.

Pero sino, como el rango es opcional, podría haber valores como `20,10[2Y,1W,5H]` en los que no podrías valerte de los caracteres alrededor de la coma.

Se puede encarar de 2 formas, ambas usando un regex:

1. **Separar** en las comas que no estén seguidas por un `]` (cuando no haya un `[` en el medio.

   ```
   String[] elementos = data.split(" *, *+(?![^]\\[]*])");
   ```

   - `*, *+` cualquier cantidad de espacios, una coma, y cualquier cantidad de espacios.
   - `(?![^]\\[]*])` la construcción `(?!`…`)` es una [inspección negativa](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special), o [*negative lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Busca que la posición actual no esté seguida por:

     - `[^]\\[]*` cualquier cantidad de [caracteres](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cc) que no sean `]` ni `[`
     - `]` y el cierre de corchetes que significaría que está dentro de un rango.

2. **Coincidir** con cada una de las partes (en vez de hacer un split)

   Para eso usamos una expresión regular que coincide con el valor y, opcionalmente con cada uno de los 3 valores del rango:

   ```
   (\d+)(?:\[(\d+)Y,(\d+)W,(\d+)H])?
   ```

   - `\d+` coincide con 1 o más [digitos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef) (0 al 9)
   - `(`…`)` es un [grupo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg), que va a capturar el texto con el que coincida.
   - `(?:`…`)?` es un [grupo sin captura](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special), pero el `?` del final lo hace [opcional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#greedy).

   De esta forma, ya tenemos todos los valores separados.

   **Código:**

   ```
   import java.util.regex.Matcher;
   import java.util.regex.Pattern;
   ```

   ```
   final String regex = "(\\d+)(?:\\[(\\d+)Y,(\\d+)W,(\\d+)H])?";
   final String texto = "1,2,3,20[4Y,2W,4H] , 10[2Y,1W,5H],4 , 5[10Y,20W,5H]";

   // así se compila siempre un regex
   final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
   final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);

   //y así se buscan siempre todas las coincidencias
   while (matcher.find()) {
       //asignamos el valor capturado por cada grupo
       String valor  = matcher.group(1);
       String rangoY = matcher.group(2);
       String rangoW = matcher.group(3);
       String rangoH = matcher.group(4);

       //imprimimos en consola
       System.out.printf("Valor: %3s - Y: %4s - W: %4s - H: %4s%n",valor,rangoY,rangoW,rangoH);
   }
   ```

   **Resultado:**

   ```
   Valor:   1 - Y: null - W: null - H: null
   Valor:   2 - Y: null - W: null - H: null
   Valor:   3 - Y: null - W: null - H: null
   Valor:  20 - Y:    4 - W:    2 - H:    4
   Valor:  10 - Y:    2 - W:    1 - H:    5
   Valor:   4 - Y: null - W: null - H: null
   Valor:   5 - Y:   10 - W:   20 - H:    5
   ```

   **Demo:** https://ideone.com/cMnbW6